# Security problem with sudo su?

Tags: security, sudo

By typing `sudo su`, any sudoer can go into the root prompt & thus change the root password!

Then what is the use of having a root & then the sudoers , because now sudoers can interfere with the root account!

Doesn't this sound ODD ??

Comment: I don't see what's wrong. Please, explain me. And I wonder whether it's a question.

Answer (score 4):

*sudo* is just a way to become root, similar to *login* and *su*. Everyone who can run *passwd* as root can change root's password, there's nothing special about *sudo*.

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't odd. This is rather what the `/etc/sudoers` file and groups are all about.

By default, anybody in the `admin` group can perform any command through `sudo` as defined by the line:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

If you think it odd that users who are noted as admins can do this, comment out that line, or, and perhaps being more sensible, you just remove them from the `admin` group if you don't trust them as a system admin.

Additionally, you can allow only certain commands for certain users or groups through `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ran another `sudo whatever` before ? In this case you won't be asked for the root password.
Of course you have to be careful with what sudoers are allowed to do !

This was already discussed a long time ago by debian users [here](http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2003/12/msg01921.html) ;-)